# Is there any way to re-render the component on onchange event on checkBox

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onchange, rerender

Here i am trying to change the style of the text to line trough onchange event but the component did not rerender and the style didn't change.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {DelAction,CompleteAction} from '../Action'
function Todo(props) {
    //assigning dipsatch 
    const dispatch=useDispatch();
    //Delete the Todo form the store

    const getStyle=()=>{
       return{ 
       textDecoration:props.todo.completed?'line-through':'none',
       backgroundColor:'rgb(20%,50%,60%)',
       borderBottom:'1px #000 dotted',
       }
   }
    return (
        <div style={getStyle()} >
            <p style={{fontSize:'20px'}}>            
            <input type="checkbox"  onChange={()=> dispatch(CompleteAction(props.todo.id))}/>
            <button style={{float:'right'}} onClick={ () => dispatch(DelAction(props.index) )} >Delete</button>
            </p>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: Can you please post `DelAction` and your reducer? I guess also you are missing `useReducer` as well in the component. Thanks!

Comment: Also, please post your `CompleteAction`. Thanks.

Comment: If you are setting `todo.completed = true` inside your reducer then your component won't know anything changed because the Object is still the same Object. Make sure you create a new Object whenever a property changes so your component knows it updated.